# How to set a DIV on the right side of the browser with percentage margin that make it get closer to the edge when resizing the browser?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I will try to explain it better here

An element placed on the page and have `10%` from the left
when the page size changes the size of the margin to the left getting smaller
`10%` from `1400px - 140px` , `10%` from `1000px - 100px` (pretty basic)

Now how do I make it happen to an element to the right
so  when browser `1400px` the margin to the right will be `140px`
and when changing the `width` of the browser to `1000px` the `margin` to the right will be `100px`

sorry I don't have an example to show

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport width to accomplish this.

```
.element {
    margin-left:10vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question doesn't provide enough information. But I will give you several possible answers.Hope they help you.

**First solution**

```
 body
 {
    position:relative;
 }

.element
{
   position:absolute;
   right: 10%
}
```

**Second solution**

```
 body
 {
     position:relative;
 }

.element
 {
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:10vw;
 }
```

**Third solution**

```
body
{
 padding-right:10%;
}
```

```css
body
{
  background-color:#FEFEFE; 
  height:650px;
  direction:rtl;
  position:relative;
  
}

.container
{
  
  width:100%;
  padding-right:10%;
  height:100%;

}

.element
{
  
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
 
}

.first
{
  background-color:red;
}

.second
{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 10%;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
  
}

.third
{
   position:absolute;
   background-color:green;
   right:10%;
   top:240px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element first">
       <h3>first div</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="element second">
       <h3>second div</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="element third">
       <h3>third div</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```